# Java Buttons does not work

Tags: user-interface, jframe, jbutton, jcomponent

I run into a problem, that I really don't know how to probably create a functional buttons in Java Swing GUI ( I guess this is how I should call it). I create a print statement to check whether if my buttons work or not,and it doesn't work.Here is my code.

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


/**
 * Create a JFrame to hold our beautiful drawings.
 */
public class Jan1UI implements ActionListener
{
    /**
     * Creates a JFrame and adds our drawings
     * 
     * @param args not used
     */

        static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        static JButton nextBut = new JButton("NEXT");
        static NextDayComponents nextDaycomponent = new NextDayComponents();


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Set up the JFrame

        nextBut.setBounds(860, 540, 100, 40);
        /*nextBut.setOpaque(false);
        nextBut.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        nextBut.setBorderPainted(false);
        */
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setTitle("Jan1UI demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(nextBut);
        frame.add(nextDaycomponent);









    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        JButton b = (JButton)e.getSource();

        if (b == nextBut)
        {
            System.out.println("ok");
        }

      }
   }
/*static class Butt implements ActionListener
{
}*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an action listener to the button, but cant do that in main as it is a static method. Instead, create a constructor to do thework similar to this:

```
public class Jan1UI implements ActionListener
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Jan1UI ui = new Jan1UI();
  }

  public Jan1UI ()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JButton nextBut = new JButton("NEXT");
    nextBut.setBounds(860, 540, 100, 40);
    nextBut.addActionListener(this);

    frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
    frame.setTitle("Jan1UI demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(nextBut);
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    System.out.println("ok");
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it works. except the button fill the whole screen again. But I guess I can fix that myself. Thank you so much for both reply that fast and  give me the full solution.

Comment: I removed the 'NextDayComponents' from the example as didnt have that code - but assume that will fill out the main area

Answer (score 0):

You must bound an ActionListener to the button:

```
nextBut.setBounds(860, 540, 100, 40);
nextBut.addActionListener(new Jan1UI());
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me where should I do that please?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot use this in a static context

 at Jan1UI.main(Jan1UI.java:41)

Comment: See my edit, right after `nextBut.setBounds(...`. Probably you should refactor your code. There are lots of Swing examples that will explain this in the common style.